# HTML Unordered List moving a line below

Tags: html, css

Ok so the problem with this code is that after the second unordered list, the third unordered list moves to a new line underneath. I don't want any of the lists to move down to a new line, but go from a  straight line from left to right.

```
<div id="plans">
    <ul>
        <li><h3>People</h3></li>
        <li>3 </li>
        <li>3 </li>
        <li>3 </li>
        <li>4 </li>
        <li>4 </li>
        <li>4 </li>
        <li>4 </li>
        <li>4 </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><h3>Humans</h3></li>
        <li>2.5</li>
        <li>2.5</li>
        <li>2.5</li>
        <li>3.5</li>
        <li>3.5</li>
        <li>3.5</li>
        <li>3.5</li>
        <li>3.5</li>    
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><h3>More Humans</h3></li>
        <li>500</li>
        <li>500</li>
        <li>500</li>
        <li>500</li>
        <li>500</li>
        <li>500</li>
        <li>500</li>
        <li>500</li>
    </ul>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#plans ul{
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: that could be due to the available width.

Comment: It is same as you want it http://jsfiddle.net/hcgt5wyx/

Comment: Odd, must be something wrong with my other CSS code then, right?

Comment: Oops, found out i had one of my divs ending tag passed the <ul> tags. Which had it's own CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [min-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width)

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jgxz4v6f/)

```
#plans {
    min-width:480px;
}
```